# Pass user-input number of variables into Matlab function handle

Tags: matlab, function, function-pointers

I am looking to use the fminsearch function for minimization. According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), fminsearch requires a function handle and initial parameter estimate.

However, I have been struggling to create a function handle that accepts a variable number of inputs. This is an example of how I would like my code to behave:

```
for i = 1:M
    fhandle = @(x)(x(i) + @fhandle)
end
```

In this example, the final fhandle is the sum of all x. Is there any way to implement this and optimize all x values such that fhandle is minimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function handles accept [varargin](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). So your exemple can be rewriten to accept a variable number of inputs:

```
fhandle = @(varargin) sum([varargin{:}])
```

and then

```
>> fhandle(1)
ans =
     1

>> fhandle(1,2)
ans =
     3

>> fhandle(1,2,3)
ans =
     6
```

Best,